# Move Confluence to subdomain (no port) on JIRA server, with Tomcat

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, jira, confluence

I'm using both JIRA and Confluence on the same server, running on Windows, using Apache Tomcat.

I have two domains pointing at the server, jira.company.com and confluence.company.com.

JIRA is running fine on port 80 in the Apache Tomcat instance, and I can get to that on the JIRA.company.com domain just fine.

Confluence is currently running on port 8090 on the same machine. What I'm trying to do is get Confluence working on the confluence.company.com domain.

Most of the documentation I can see is about configuring virtual hosts and reverse proxies in httpd.conf, however in Apache Tomcat all I have to work with is the server.xml file.

I understand I can add another host to the JIRA server.xml file to point to a different docBase for Confluence, but I have a feeling this breaks Atlassian's own recommendations found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf57/installing-confluence-and-jira-together-701435562.html).

When I add an additional host entry into Confluence's server.xml it's ignored, and the confluence.company.com domain sends me through to JIRA.

I've done some searching and found similar questions but they don't seem to apply to my configuration - they all mention httpd.conf which isn't present on my server.

My questions:

- Can I run Confluence on the subdomain by adding an extra  entry in JIRA's server.xml? If possible, is this bad?
- Is there another way to get my Confluence Apache instance listening on port 80 but on it's own domain name?

I can do all this on IIS with my eyes shut, but in Apache/Tomcat I'm a little lost. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is not really meant to directly handle incoming requests as usually an Apache or other proxy is put in front of it to hide the ports and provide other useful features you would need for Single Sign On etc. Note that there is a difference between the Apache Webserver, which is commonly only called "Apache" and "Apache Tomcat", which is only an application server made by the Apache Foundation community and named "Tomcat". Tomcat only supports basic webserver functionality.

In any case, you can use the IIS as a webserver and proxy to forward the requests and at the same time hide the ports of the applications. I personally haven't used IIS but Atlassian offers a thorough explanation for the Confluence and/or JIRA integration with IIS as a proxy: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/integrating-jira-applications-with-iis-802593039.html

The page covers JIRA for the most part but section 4 also has additional information if you want to hook up both JIRA and Confluence on the same server, which is exactly your use case.